# Rotate polar stereographic subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am making a figure with subplots which are north polar stereographic projections. I also created a custom boundary shape to display subplot as a circle. However once reprojected, I want to be able to rotate the map, since my data is focusing on the US and thus I was hoping that each subplot would have the US facing "up," thus I would need to rotate it 270 degrees / -90 degrees.

Minimalistic code example pulled from [cartopy example](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/lines_and_polygons/always_circular_stereo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-and-polygons-always-circular-stereo-py)

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline # for notebook

map_projection = ccrs.NorthPolarStereo(central_longitude=0, )
data_projection = ccrs.PlateCarree()
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
center, radius = [0.5, 0.5], 0.5  # by changing radius we can zoom in/out
verts = np.vstack([np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]).T
circle = mpl.path.Path(verts * radius + center)
plot_extent=[-179.9,180, 30, 90]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(6,6), dpi=100, subplot_kw=dict(projection=map_projection))
ax1.set_boundary(circle, transform=ax1.transAxes)  
ax1.coastlines(linewidths=1.0, color='grey')
ax1.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyles='--', color='dimgrey', linewidths=0.8 )
ax1.set_extent(plot_extent, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(),)
gl = ax1.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,
                  linewidth=1, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--', zorder=10)
```

I haven't yet found any good examples or documentation for what I am trying to do, however I am new to using matplotlib/cartopy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `central_longitude=-90`.

So:

```
map_projection = ccrs.NorthPolarStereo(central_longitude=-90)
```